# VBA - How do I hide rows based on a certain criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide all the rows if the B column value has the value "x". This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub HideRowsOOS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B")
        If cell.Value = "x" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "B2:B" is not a valid range reference. The normal approach is to [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and then include that in your reference.

Comment: Note that you are not referring to the `With ActiveSheet`... you would need to add a period `.` in front of the `Range` call to actually do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Range("B2:B")
```

with:

```
Intersect(Range("B:B"),ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
```

*(you could also remove the `With` statement)*

Comment: just to be clear, `.UsedRange` can have unintended consequences and significanty affect performance if the are cells that appear to be blank but house formatting and such in areas where there is no data.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  You are correct.  The suggestion may test some extra cells unnecessarily, but its better than test the entire column **B**

Answer (score 1):

I will offer this optimized procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideRowsOOS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as neeeded

        Dim lastRow as Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

            If cell.Value = "x" Then 

                Dim collect as Range
                If collect Is Nothing Set collect = cell: Else Set collect = Union(collect, cell)

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

    collect.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```